# Pick Up Delivery with Time Window example/ Benchmark Problem

Tags: vehicle-routing, benchmark

I am trying to solve a pick up and delivery problem with time window (variant of vehicle routing problem). Would anyone be able to direct me to some example problems with known solution or benchmark problems that you have used ?

Comment: would you see [this](https://www.sintef.no/projectweb/top/pdptw/li-lim-benchmark/) and [this](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/wr2ct4r22f/2) link? Also, you could find a lot of related papers by googling. :)

Comment: Thanks so much . I really appreciate your time.